# how do i manipulate decimals in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, numbers, decimal

I have a data frame (df) like this:

```
euro    token
200.0   65.78947368421053
9997.8  2631.0
```

Whenever there is only a .0, I want to get rid of the .0 but when there is a single decimal like .8 in "euro" I want to have to decimals like you would normally have with a currency.
So the definition for the "euro" column would be 2 decimals, except when there are only 0. For the "token" column it would be 18 decimals, not showing the trailing 0 and no decimals when there are only 0.

I read a lot now, but don't even find where to start with this. Anybody?

## Updated example on further issues

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

min_invest = 200
cps_exchange_rate_eur = Decimal(38) / Decimal(10)

df = pd.read_excel(file.xlsx,
               index_col=None,
               dtype={'euro': float},
               na_values='NA'
               )

print(df.head())
print(df.dtypes)

      email              euro
0     first@gmail.com    600.00
1     second@web.de      200.00
2     third@web.de       1997.80
3     fourth@gmail.com   200.00
4     fifth@gmx.ch       9997.80

email     object
euro     float64
dtype: object
```

Now I'm trying to get the 2 Decimals fix. :-)

```
df.loc[:, 'euro'] = np.round(df['euro'], decimals=2)
df.loc[:, 'euro_cent'] = (df['euro'] * 100).astype(int)

print(df.head()
print(df.dtypes)

                         email    euro  euro_cent
0              first@gmail.com  600.00      60000
1                second@web.de  200.00      20000
2                 third@web.de  1997.80     199779
3             fourth@gmail.com  200.00      20000
4                 fifth@gmx.ch  9997.80     999779

email         object
euro         float64
euro_cent      int64
dtype: object
```

As you can see, it's messed up in row 2 and 4. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Thanks Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the stored values to be exact to two decimal places, then you should do your arithmetic with the `decimal` package.  If you want to keep the full accuracy, but print only two decimal places on output, then see the various tutorials on Python formatting, such as `"{:.2f}".format(euro)`.

RESPONSE TO OP COMMENT

But look at how you got the exchange rate: you assigned a `float` value, so it's no longer guaranteed to be *exactly* 3.8 in base 10; rather, it's the closest approximation in binary.  I get `3.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`.

If you want *exact* results from what you see on the printed page, then you *cannot* use fractional, non-binary numbers in your computations.  To get an exact 3.8, use `Decimal(38) / Decimal(10)`.

RESPONSE TO NEXT COMMENT

It's the same issue: you're using an input package that reads into type `float`, which does not have the same representation as the numeric strings in your file.  The fraction `.8` cannot be represented exactly in binary.  Rows 2 and 4 are messed up because you used `float` values instead of `Decimal`.  Rounding to 2 places does not mean that the computer can now represent exacts hundredths; it simply means that you get the closest available value.  For instance:

```
>>> np.round(0.8, 2)
0.80000000000000004
```

One way to deal with this is to do *all* of your arithmetic -- including the starting values -- in `Decimal`.  Another way is to accept the minuscule errors until it's time to print or record the results ... *then* round to two decimals places on the way out.

Comment: I need to get back to you on this one. I guess I understood what you said and figured out the formatting part. But I still have a problem wrapping my head around it. I have a variable `exchange_rate = 3.8` and a dataframe with with numbers as floats. I now need to divide every number within the dataframe by the exchange_rate. I imported pandas and decimal. Example: `df['euro'].apply(Decimal) / Decimal(exchange_rate)` where df['euro'] = 760. This should get me exactly 200 but it gives me 200.000000000000009349. And I don't understand why.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. I guess I got it now. :-)

Comment: I need to get back again. Trust me I don't to. But this f... float is driving me crazy. This time, I'm getting an Excel document with two columns "email" and "euro". There seam to be especially two values 1998,80 and 9997,80. As long as I don't touch them, everything seams fine. But when I start calculating it gets crazy. For instance, when I multiply them by 100 to get rid of the Decimals, I get 199879 and 999779 instead of 199880 and 999780. I already tried to import it as object instead of float, but this somehow get's changed on it's own. I'll update my example above. Pls help :-)

Comment: You might look up a web page on working with monetary amounts; Stack Overflow isn't really intended for successive refinement of a topic such as this.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this way:

```
#sample
euro = [2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0, 5.4444]

new_euro = [round(x) if x == round(x) else "{0:.2f}".format(x) for x in euro]

print(new_euro)
[2, '2.30', 3, 4, '5.44']
```